# splitting an image horizontaly in Nodejs with sharp loses quality

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

I want to split an image horizontaly with sharp but the halves lose a bit of size, the input image i tried is 10mb, the halves i get are 3mb and 2mb

```
// Input image path
const imagePath = "./images/x.jpg";

// Read the image using sharp
sharp(imagePath)
  .metadata()
  .then((metadata) => {
    // Calculate the height at which the image should be split
    const splitHeight = Math.floor(metadata.height / 2);

    // Split the image horizontally
    sharp(imagePath)
      .extract({ left: 0, top: 0, width: metadata.width, height: splitHeight })
      .toFile("top-half.jpg");

    sharp(imagePath)
      .extract({
        left: 0,
        top: splitHeight,
        width: metadata.width,
        height: splitHeight,
      })
      .toFile("bottom-half.jpg");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error splitting the image:", err);
  });
```

Comment: You are saving as JPG which is a lossy format. You can't expect pixel perfection after editing from lossy to lossy (like file sizes summing to the original). Try your splitting with lossless PNGs.

Comment: Sharp has a `quality` option that affects how lossy the newly created JPEG is.  The default value is 80 (on a 0-100 scale).  You can try increasing that to 90 or 95 or even 100 to investigate different tradeoffs between image quality and file size (higher quality images results in larger files).

Comment: @JustAskin Saving to a PNG makes the result halves trice the size of the original image (32Mb)

Comment: If you have a question, please edit it into the OP. As it stands currently, the title, text, and comment are only statements, and doesn't make it clear what would qualify as an answer or resolution for you.